# Changing Label text through button in ios programmatically

Tags: ios

I want to to know how to change the text of label through button programmatically? Can any one suggest some good tutorials for IOS development?

Comment: The best tutorial I know of for this situation would be the documentation. Even a quick glance at it would probably do.

Comment: This question is off-topic. Please take a [tour].

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
[myButton setTitle: @"myTitle" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
```

[Here's a link to the apple docs. it'll help you out a bunch](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: Why was this answer accepted? This doesn't come close to answering the question. It doesn't explain how to change a label's text when a button is tapped.